# Обработка нажатия на кнопку и получение текста из поля

Tags: java, jframe

Собственно в названии вопроса и проблема. У меня есть несколько классов. Вот первый

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GraphicalDisplay {

private JFrame frame;
private JLabel titleLabel1;
private JLabel titleLabel2;
private JLabel titleLabel3;
private JLabel titleLabel4;
private JLabel titleLabel5;
private TextField text;
private Button button;
private JLabel titleLabel6;


public GraphicalDisplay(String title1, String title2, String title3, String title4) {
    buildFrame();
    titleLabel1.setText(title1);
    titleLabel2.setText(title2);
    titleLabel3.setText(title3);
    titleLabel6.setText(title4);
}

private void buildFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame("Графический дисплей");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1));

    titleLabel1 = new JLabel();
    titleLabel2 = new JLabel();
    titleLabel3 = new JLabel();
    titleLabel6 = new JLabel();
    text = new TextField("", 50);
    button = new Button("Ввести");
    button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
    frame.add(titleLabel1);
    frame.add(titleLabel2);
    frame.add(titleLabel3);
    frame.add(text);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(titleLabel6);


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(ActionEvent e) {
        getText1();
    }

    public String getText1() {
        String textbutton = text.getText();
        return textbutton;
    }

    public void setText4(String text) {
        titleLabel6.setText(text);
    }

}
```

И вот второй

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class SupportSystem
{
private InputReader reader;
private Responder responder;
public GraphicalDisplay display1;

public SupportSystem()
{
    reader = new InputReader();
    responder = new Responder();
}

public void start()
{
    boolean finished = false;

    printWelcome();

    while(!finished) {
        String textbutton = display1.mouseClicked(MouseEvent);
        HashSet<String> input = reader.getInput(textbutton);


        if(input.contains("exit")==true) {
            finished = true;
        }
        else {
            String response = responder.generateResponse(input);
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }
    printGoodbye();
}

public void printWelcome()
{
    display1 = new GraphicalDisplay("Добро пожаловать в техподдержку DodgySoft.", "Расскажите нам о вашей проблеме.", "Введите 'exit' для выхода из системы.","");
}

private void printGoodbye()
{
    display1.setText4("Приятно было пообщаться. До свидания...");
}
```

}

Изучая то, что есть в интернете находил всякие обработчики, слушатели, ивенты и т.д. Сам не могу понять как это должно даже выглядеть, не говоря уже о том чтобы работало. Помогите!

Comment: Я добавил способы обработки нажатия кнопок на клавиатуре.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для получения текста из JFrame поля используйте метод .getText() и записывайте этот текст в String переменную. Например, есть такой код.

```
   private JTextField output = new JTextField();
   private String getteroftext;
   output.setText("Текст, который нужно получить");
   getteroftext = output.getText();
```

Далее делаем, что хотим со строкой, в ней будет текст из поля output

Обработку нажатия на кнопку графического интерфейса  можно делать таким образом.

```
   // Реализуем кнопку стирание
   // Объявляем кнопку с текстом "С"
   private JButton backspace = new JButton("C");
   // Добавляем "Ослеживатель события"
   backspace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   // Используем переопределение
   @Override
   // Добавляем событие нажатия на кнопку e — название события
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // объявляем временную переменную, содержащую текст из поля output
                String tmp =output.getText();
                /* Задаем полю output текст из переменной tmp посимвольно, 
                 от символа с индексом 0 до (индекс последнего символа в 
                 строке-1)*/  
                 output.setText(tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1));
            }
        });
```

Если нужно обработать нажатие на какую-то клавишу, скажем F1...F9 или Tab, Space и так далее, используют команду виртуальной кнопки

```
        VK_НазваниеКнопки
```

Например так

```
      // Реализуем ручной ввод
      private void manualInput() {
    ActionListener l = (ActionEvent button_is_presed)->{
        JButton b =(JButton) button_is_presed.getSource();
        output.setText(output.getText()+b.getText());
    };
    for(JButton b :numbers){
        b.addActionListener(l);
    }

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        char symvol = e.getKeyChar();
      if(symvol==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
      String tmp =output.getText();
      output.setText(tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1));
```

Если Вам нужно записать в поле output текст с клавиатуры, я бы посоветовал сделать так

```
   addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        char symvol = e.getKeyChar();
```

Обрабатываем нажатие на кнопку мыши

```
     // Делаем наш класс наследником класса MouseAdapter
     public class SupportSystem extends MouseAdapter {
     // Далее можем использовать все методы класса-родителя
     // Пишем свой код... ...доходим до обработки события нажатия на мышь

     // Используем метод mousePresed
     public void mousePresed(MouseEvent mouse_is_presed){
     // Пишем что должно происходить при возникновении события 
     // mouse_is_presed

     } 
     // Не забываем закрыть класс
     }
```

Если нужно закрыть окно по нажатию на "Крестик", то существуют специальные функции, и мышь вам в этом случае трогать не надо. Закрытие приложения делается так

```
 private JFrame ourMainFrame;
 // Задаем размеры, делаем окно видимым и задаем другие параметры... 
 // ... Доходим до параметра поведения при нажатии на "крестик"  
 ourMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Это конечно вроде бы должно работать, но что тогда мне писать в цикле? У меня во втором классе цикл где я как раз пытаюсь сделать нажатие на кнопку. String textbutton = display1.mouseClicked(MouseEvent); Как мне это тогда заменить?

Comment: Так Вам нужно обработать нажатие на кнопку мыши? А писали, что в названии вопроса и есть суть проблемы... Сейчас добавлю в ответ обработку нажатия мыши. Почитайте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask