# Как определить нажатие клавиши Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

Я делаю игру на графическом интерфейсе Java Swing, и мне нужно проверить нажата ли клавиша управления, в этом случае "w". Желательно в одном классе с игрой и минимум кода. Должно получиться что-то такое:

```
if(key w pressed) {
    playerY += 1;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отслеживание нажатия клавиш java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881823/), [Обработка нажатия на кнопку и получение текста из поля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927162/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте Key Listener и метод keyPressed(KeyEvent e). Например проверяйте код нажатой клавиши, и в зависимости от значения вызывайте обработчик.

Пример:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    /*
    ...
    */ 
    panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 87)
                System.out.println("Нажата W");
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == 65)
                System.out.println("Нажата A");
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == 83)
                System.out.println("Нажата S");
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == 68)
                System.out.println("Нажата D");             
        }
    });
```

Более детально - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: Это работает, только в моем случае при нажатии клавиш курсор пользователя сфокусирован на JTextArea(имитация консольного приложения), и буквы просто пишутся в эту текстовую область, а KeyListener их не обрабатывает. Как можно поступить в таком случае?

Comment: @user530939 Обработчик у вас на какой элемент повешен? Должен вызываться пока окно в фокусе.

Comment: Точно, забыл заменить panel на screen! Спасибо)

Comment: @user530939 Если вам помог ответ, не забывайте его отмечать как решение.